# How to set / and /admin paths creating 2 applications(front, admin) in codeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

How to set / and /admin paths creating 2 applications(front, admin) in codeIgniter

i mean how to write it in the .htaccess, to have working the both paths from 2 applications

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use htaccess for that if you don't have to fro some weird reason.

Just create **additional route** for admin in routes.php or create an admin controller **admin.php** or a module called **admin** if you are using HMVC.

Btw. you really have two different application folders for admin and frontend?

It has to be very complicated (I mean a lot of additional code) to access stuff from one app in another or?

Answer (score 1):

Yea I would agree with Derfder here. I my CI application there is a front end and backend, there is no htaccess modifications related to it.

I simply use an admin.php in the controllers folder to hold all the pages for admin related tasks. I make sure to secure this down by checking if they an admin or not in the methods, or in the constructor.